# Convergence/divergence of the series $\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{z + n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let us have a series $\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z + n}$, where $z \in \mathbb{C}$. I intended to use the Dirichlet test, where $\sum (-1)^n$ is a bounded complex series, and $\frac{1}{z + n}$ is actually going to zero. This would ensure the convergence of the series for all $z \in \mathbb{C} \cap z \notin \mathbb{Z}^+$.

The problem is, the Dirichlet test requires the condition that $\frac{1}{z + n}$ is decreasing! However, since the term $z$ is complex, this assumption is violated. Thus, the test cannot be applied.

How can this be solved in the most traditional way? Is it possible to apply Dirichlet test somehow here?

Comment: Dirichlet test isn't like big hard theorems that are more useful as black boxes. The test's proof is actually more useful than the test itself. Just apply Abel's summation by parts. The sums of $(-1)^n$ is bounded, as you said. Now, the other factor decreasing to zero is only used in order to have $\sum_n(a_n-a_{n+1})$ converging absolutely. Well, you can test that directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$${(-1)^n\over z+n}={(-1)^n(\overline z+n)\over(z+n)(\overline z+n)}={(-1)^n\overline z\over|z+n|^2}+{(-1)^nn\over|z+n|^2}$$

The sum $\sum{(-1)^n\overline z\over|z+n|^2}$ is absolutely convergent, while for each $z$, the sequence $n/|z+n|^2$ is eventually decreasing, so the alternating series $\sum{(-1)^nn\over|z+n|^2}$ converges conditionally.

Comment: Thx, this is actually a very neat solution in comparison to what i tried.

Comment: You're welcome. And kudos for realizing you can't just say "Dirichlet" and call it a day!

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of seeing this is to combine two terms.

Note that $\frac{1}{z + 2n} - \frac{1}{z + 2n + 1} = \frac{1}{(z + 2n)(z + 2n + 1)}$.

Now you can use anything you know to show that the sum $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(z + 2n)(z + 2n + 1)}$ converges (e.g. compare the absolute value with $\frac{c}{n^2}$ for some constant $c$). This, combined with the fact that $\frac{1}{z + n}$ tends to $0$, shows the convergence of the original series.